# Moving Firefox addon to repository

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've developed a Firefox addon. Let's say *addon.xpi*. I hosted it on my site, but now it also available in the Mozilla repo.

So, I want to move all existing users (who installed *addon.xpi* from my site) to Mozilla repo. As I understand, since the both addons (on my site and in the repo) have the same ID, I need just put some "Mozilla repo" link to *UpdateURL* for selfhosted version, and then next time all users will install updates from the repo.

Am I right? Does somebody know general update URL for addons in Mozilla repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than that - just remove `<em:updateURL>` from your `install.rdf` file and publish an update. By default the update URL in the browser's `extensions.update.url` preference is used. And that one always  points to addons.mozilla.org, so once your users update they will get future updates from there.

Or you can even modify to `update.rdf` file currently on your server and change `<em:updateLink>` entry - point it to the XPI file on addons.mozilla.org.

Comment: Thank you. That's really simple :)